# remover um item especifico de uma lista encadeada em c

Tags: c

tenho a

```
    struct LDISP
{
int  idAviao;
struct LDISP *prox;
};
typedef struct LDISP ldisp;
```

ja tenho o processo de adiconar gostaria de saber como posso remover de uma lista ldisp um item cujo tem o int igual ao idaviao

Comment: Lembra-te que a remocao do primeiro item da lista tem complicacoes extra.

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? Sabe ao menos procurar o item que vai ser removido? Edite a pergunta para adicionar esse tipo de detalhes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para remover um elemento da lista, primeiro precisa verificar se ele é **0** ou se é **N**.

> Quando posição for **0**, deve-se percorrer o valor com sua lista original.
>
> Quando posição for **n**, pode-se usar uma variável auxiliar para ajudar.

```
int remove_item(ldisp **l, int id){
    if(!(*l)) // encerra se não houver item na lista
        return 0;

    ldisp *aux = (*l);
    if((*l)->idAviao == id){ // verifica se posição == 0
        (*l) = (*l)->prox; // coloca a lista no próximo item
        free(aux); // limpa a memória

        return 1; // finaliza com verdadeiro
    }

    ldisp *prev;
    while(aux){ // verifica se aux não chegou ao fim e percorre a posição
        prev = aux; // prev guarda valor da remoção
        aux = aux->prox;
        if(aux && aux->idAviao == id){ // verifica o id do avião
            prev->prox = aux->prox;
            free(aux);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: desculpe pela ignorancia mas o que seria o **l com apenas um asteeriso e o ponteiro, que parametro devo passar nesse caso?

Comment: esse codigo remove a posicao n da lista o que eu quero e remover quando o conteudo for igual ao numero do aviao mais obrigado mesmo assim

Comment: o `*l` serve para pegar o valor de dentro do endereço de memória de l, quando se trabalha com ponteiros, deve se usar desse jeito senão não consegue remover o item.

Comment: @user2296455 alterei o código para remover pelo id do avião, da para perceber que ambos são iguais, só muda a verificação

Comment: `**l` é um ponteiro de um ponteiro. `l` tem um ponteiro para outra variável. `**l` é o ponteiro da variável.

Comment: obrigado funcionou

Comment: se o código foi resolveu seu problema, você pode clicar no **v** ao lado da respostas para indicar que sua pergunta foi resolvida